# Configuring publication target for SmartTarget 2014

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

I have installed SmartTarget 2014 SP1 on Tridion 2013, and now need to configure the target for development. I have two targets - DD4T and non DD4T and a single odata preview service. I want to use the same odata endpoints in both the targets but it's not allowing me which is correct as per the manual.

So my question is do I need to create separate odata endpoints for each target. So if there are 5 targets and each needs to be smarttarget enabled so do I need five separate odata endpoints which means 5 websites in IIS. Will it be a good and acceptable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. It sounds like you want to serve the exact same Promotions on all 5 targets, in which case I would recommend that you only have one Promotion List (so just choose one of the targets and configure the Targeting tab on that one).

Then on the web sites you just link them all to the same Fredhopper in the SmartTarget configuration.

Comment: Ok.. in case if I want a separate set of promotion for the another target then a new endpoint is required right?

Comment: Yes. So a unique list of Promotions = 1 unique web service = 1 unique Fredhopper instance.